# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin html5

Tags: json, html, google-api

I am trying to retrieve the "types" data from the GOOGLE API for POI by calling the API, getting a JSON object, and then print it. The call to the URL works fine and returns a JSON object, but everytime I try to access it, even print it on screen , I get the error on Chrome's console "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I have also tried using $.getJSON and included callback=? in the URL , but no luck... Any help will be welcome.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Google Geolocation Test </title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=51.2780637,1.0852839&radius=0.1&sensor=true&key=MYKEY&callback=?';

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);

})

</script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have seen that many encountered this issue. Google apparently leaves you no option but to use the API for maps using a server connection. For those who only wish to retrieve information about places using the google maps API, which in the JSON provided by Google, I recommend using FourSquare's API instead, which allows cross-platform queries, something that Google Maps apparently does not.

And so, as for the solution, you can use the code above, but replace the content of the var url with this:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&radius=10&oauth_token=YOURKEY&v=20130628&callback=?

You can get a Key and the full code by registering on https://developer.foursquare.com/